# How to implement a convolution function in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to learn VHDL. I wrote this code to do a convolution, but it doesn't work: the output doesn't change from 0 when I run it. I tried adding a clock but it doesn't work, either (do I need one?). What's wrong?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
package mypack is
type real_vector is array (integer range <>) of real;
end mypack;

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
--use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use work.mypack.all;

entity convolution is
port (x:in real_vector(0 to 3);
      y:in real_vector(0 to 1);
      f:out real_vector (0 to 4));
end convolution;

architecture Behavioral of convolution is
--signal temp : real_vector (0 to 4):= (others => 0.0);
--signal enable : std_logic :='0';
begin
process (x,y)
variable sum :real;
begin

  for n in f'range loop
     enable <= '0';
     for k in y'range loop
        sum:=sum + x(k)*y(n-k);
      end loop;
     -- temp(n) <= sum;
      f(n) <= sum ;
      sum:=0.0;
  end loop;
enable <= '1';

--if (enable'event and enable='1') then
--    f <= temp;
--end if;

end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: You say "It doesn't work". Explain more.

Comment: Commented out code just clutters it up. It is best practice to remove this.

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to say for certain why f is getting set to 0, but I do see problems with your code.

For starters, sum is never initialized to 0.0 near the beginning of the process.  You set it at the end, after f is assigned, but it makes no difference there.  With some synthesizers/simulators your code might work, but it is still bad practice and won't always work.  It is better to initialize sum.

Next, look at this code segment.  I have substituted 'range with the actual values for clarity:

```
for n in 0 to 4 loop
     for k in 0 to 1 loop
        sum := sum + x(k) * y(n-k);
```

What happens if n=0 and k=1?  Then you are indexing y(-1), which is an invalid index.  I am surprised that your simulator is not complaining about this.

So I don't know why f is zero; but with sum not being initialized and using invalid indexes for y, you certainly won't get the results you expect.

Answer (score -2):

Algorithm for linear convolution
Where, l=length of x(n)
m=length of h(n)
N=l+m-1=length of output

```
1.  Start
2.  Initialize sum=0,result array={0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
3.  For i in 0 to N-1 do
4.  Sum=0
5.  For j in 0 to l-1 do
6.  For k in m-1 to 0 do
7.  If (i=j+k) then product=x(k)*h(k-j)--------------this  product will be calculated using Vedic multiplier.
8.  Sum=sum+product
9.  End loop k;
10.  End loop j
11.  Result(i)=sum
12.  End loop i;
13.  End
```

Comment: I think OP was not asking about the algorithm.

Comment: In addition, the subject clearly states VHDL. And what on earth do Vedic multipliers have to do with it?